# correct format of default value for number data type oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, navicat, oracle19c

I have a table structure code for PL/SQL as below(this code is just a line of code creation):

```
"VERSION" NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 1  1 105331  NOT NULL
```

the problem is with the numbers after DEFAULT. Does anybody know whether it makes sense? If it does, what does it mean? I get a ' missing right parenthesis' error when I run the whole code but when I remove this line it works. (this code has not been written by me and I do not have access to the developer who wrote it)

Comment: It does not make sense to me.  And it generates a compiler error, so it doesn't make sense to Oracle either.  If I were to speculate, it might be an attempt at a `check` constraint.

Comment: If you have an environment/schema where the table already exists, see how it is defined there, maybe with `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` or using a tool like SQL Developer to see the   statement(s) needed to recreate it.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anybody know whether it makes sense?

No, it does not make sense and it is not syntactically valid code.

`1` and `105331` are each numbers but combined `1  1 105331` is not a number, its is 3 numbers and that does not make sense to try to put 3 numbers into a single `NUMBER` column.

As the SQL parser parses the statement it gets to:

```sql
"VERSION" NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 1
```

And that, so far, is valid and then it reads the next number and that is invalid syntax so Oracle complains about the invalid syntax and suggests that one thing that would be valid would be to terminate the DDL statement with a closing right-parenthesis (which is where the error message comes from).

Typically, a ([semantic](https://semver.org/)) version identifier is a string with 3 full-stop delimited numbers indicating major, minor and patch version numbers (and this is not something that you can express as a single decimal number) so you would have:

```
"VERSION" VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT '1.1.105331' NOT NULL
```

Whether or not this makes sense to convert the column to this format is something that you would have to determine as the meaning of the columns is a business decision and not something that we have the domain knowledge to determine; however, your current code is syntactically invalid and we can tell you that is doesn't make sense and that it will not compile.